Standardizing variables for a regression model vs weights in a regression model?
I have a longitudinal GAM (General Additive Model) regression in R.
Here is the general form of the model and data (response is between 0 and 1). All variables are calculated at the state level (e.g. state GDP, disease rate within the state):
gam_model <- gam(
    response ~ 
        te(time_var, var1) +
        te(time_var, var2) +
        s(time_var, by = state) +
        s(state, bs = "re"),
    data = sample_data,
    method = "REML",
    family = betar(link = "logit")
)

   state   time_var population   var1  var2 response
 state_1 2005-01-01    1000000 500000 10000     0.45
 state_1 2005-02-01    1001000 520000 12000     0.47
 state_1 2005-03-01    1002001 540000 11000     0.46
 state_1 2005-04-01    1003002 560000 13000     0.48
 state_2 2005-01-01     200000 100000  2000     0.42
 state_2 2005-02-01     200200 105000  2400     0.44
 state_2 2005-03-01     200400 110000  2200     0.43
 state_2 2005-04-01     200600 115000  2600     0.45

Here is the problem I have:

data is available by state (multiple states, 1 country), however each state has a different population
This makes me think that something needs to be done to the model to prevent states with larger populations having a stronger effect on the response compared to states with smaller populations
I have the population of each state

I am thinking of using the following weight formula (I got this idea from here https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-024-54441-x):
$$avg\_weight_s = \frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^{T} \frac{\ln(population_{s,t})}{\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N} \ln(population_{i,t})}$$
where:

$T$ is the total number of time periods
$N$ is the total number of states
$population_{s,t}$ is the population of state $s$ at time $t$
$population_{i,t}$ represents the population of each state $i$ at time $t$ in the
Note that even though I have multiple time points for each state ... each state gets a single weight (that will be used throughout). I just wanted to reiterate this point.

This leads me to consider different model options:
# option 1: unstandardized, no weights

    gam_model <- gam(
        response ~ 
            te(time_var, var1) +
            te(time_var, var2) +
            s(time_var, by = state) +
            s(state, bs = "re"),
        data = sample_data,
        method = "REML",
        family = betar(link = "logit")
    )


# option 2 : standardized, no weights

    gam_model <- gam(
        response ~ 
            te(time_var, var1/population) +
            te(time_var, var2/population) +
            s(time_var, by = state) +
            s(state, bs = "re"),
        data = sample_data,
        method = "REML",
        family = betar(link = "logit")
    )


# option 3: unstandardized, weights

    gam_model <- gam(
        response ~ 
            te(time_var, var1) +
            te(time_var, var2) +
            s(time_var, by = state) +
            s(state, bs = "re"),
        data = sample_data,
    weights = avg_weight,
        method = "REML",
        family = betar(link = "logit")
    )



# option 4: standardized, weights

    gam_model <- gam(
        response ~ 
            te(time_var, var1/population) +
            te(time_var, var2/population) +
            s(time_var, by = state) +
            s(state, bs = "re"),
        data = sample_data,
    weights = avg_weight,
        method = "REML",
        family = betar(link = "logit")
    )

I am a bit confused here as to which of these options is logically correct. I think some of them might be overkill and others are plain incorrect. Is there a way to sort this out?

Possibly a better option is trying to use the same population size for all with matching. See Matching Methods if there are enough characteristics to match.

thank you for this suggestion! when it comes to matching, I am familiar with things like propensity score matching which is used more in experimental studies to match similar  individuals from two different groups (e.g. placebo vs treatment) to measure the effect and adjust for confounders. In my case, would this still be necessary?

@user_436830.can you state what the response is (what it is measuring)?

@user_436830  Matching technique  is used to get comparable samples in two different sets. In this case,  resample all sets to the same size, so that weighting is not needed. Matching is used so that they are comparable as much as possible.

Matching is not a good approach in this setting and weighting is probably not appropriate either.  It all depends on the response.  You didn’t tell us what it was.  If the response is a person-oriented response then it makes sense to profit from larger sample sizes in larger states.

@GavinSimpson : the response measures the average value of a variable each month at the state level (e.g. average economic growth)

@FrankHarrell : I think Gavin asked the same question and I answered him

First,

This makes me think that something needs to be done to the model to prevent states with larger populations having a stronger effect on the response compared to states with smaller populations

Your data is at the state level, you seem to have one row per state, per time point. Your model doesn't include population at all. So a state's populataion will have no effect on your results here. The problem you're worried about would arise if you instead had data for each person at each time point, with people nested within states, and one solution to this would be to aggregate the data to the format you have it in.
Second, in the rest of your question, you seem to be discussing a completely different problem: that some of your variables (e.g. GDP) are not normalised. by population. Whether you should use something like GDP or GDP per capita is a very context-dependant decision (see https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/10.1098/rsos.230832, and many other questions here for a primer), and you haven't provided nearly enough information to try to answer it here, so if that's your problem, I suggest asking a new, more focused question after reading the paper above.
Third, as mentioned in the comments, what's wrong with larger states having more influence on your results? Are you worried that the effect you're interested in may work differently for smaller or larger states? In which case, you should consider including state population in your model as an interaction term.
Finally, if you do want larger states to have MORE influence in your data, and your data is at the state level (which is the case in the paper you cite), then yes, using regression weights is a sensible idea, but I have no idea why that paper makes up their own weighting scheme, or why reviewers let them do it (Scientific Reports is a journal known for poor peer review standards), but the standard weighting would just be weight = population / sum(population).

Without applying weight, each state-month combination enters the likelihood function once, so it does not give states of different population sizes any higher or lower impacts when estimating the model -- each state is equally important. The resulting model depicts a typical state: draw a random state, what is the expected relationship between the response and predictors in a given year?
Instead of assigning each observation a weight related to population size, you should consider a model that includes population size as a predictor (i.e., covariate, control variable, ...) as well as its interaction with other predictors (i.e., var1 and var2). The resulting model also depicts a typical state: draw a random state of a given population size, what is the expected relationship between the response and predictors in a given year?
The cited paper Dong, E., Nixon, K., & Gardner, L. M. (2024). A population level study on the determinants of COVID-19 vaccination rates at the U.S. county level. Scientific Reports, 14(1), 4277. https://doi.org/10.1038/s41598-024-54441-x uses weights, because it attempts to give the national average unvaccination rates, which equates the probability of unvaccination on the personal level considering residents among all counties the population. If weights are not used, the model may as well reveal the unvaccination rates of a typical county. For example, three counties with whether the unvaccination rate exceeds a threshold $y_1 = 0, y_2 = 1, y_3 = 0$ and population size $n_1, n_2, n_3$. In building a population-average or individual-level model of discrete responses, the likelihood function is $L = f(y_1)^{n_1} f(y_2)^{n_2} f(y_3)^{n_3}$ and the corresponding is $\ln{L} = {n_1}\ln{f(y_1)} + {n_2}\ln{f(y_2)} + {n_3}\ln{f(y_3)}$ where $f(\cdot)$ is the probability density or mass function, just as if the row of $y_i$ is copied and pasted $n_i$ times. This is usually applied in stratified sampling to retrieve the ground mean. Proportionally changing all weights by the same constant does not affect estimates of coefficients and standard errors, but it changes ANOVA table and sum of squares. However, the meaning of weights in the likelihood function can be different for continuous responses. See the example of weighted linear regression at How is Gaussian log likelihood value calculated in weight linear regression?. I am not sure how weights are accounted in the likelihood function of a beta regression. If $y_i$ represents the fraction of vaccinated, you can verify in a small example whether a null model with weights get to the population average which should be $(y_1n_1 + y_2n_2 + y_3n_3)/(n_1 + n_2 + n_3)$.
Use per capita measures like var1/population and var2/population if they help interpretation, but neither excludes the inclusion of population as another predictor. In economics, dividing capital input by labour input (i.e., population size) to predict economic output assumes constant returns to scale of economy, which holds empirically at the metropolitan level. See Sarkar, S., Arcaute, E., Hatna, E., Alizadeh, T., Searle, G., & Batty, M. (2020). Evidence for localization and urbanization economies in urban scaling. Royal Society Open Science, 7(3), 191638. https://doi.org/10.1098/rsos.191638. Without adding population as another predictor, the model basically enforces population to have a constrained pattern: Its reciprocal has the effect equal to the sum of coefficients of var1 and var2. When both var1/population and population are predictors, the constraint relaxes, and one can interpret the coefficient of the former as: Given a certain population of $n$, every $x$ amount increase in var1 is associated with an increase in the logit of the proportion by $\hat{\beta} * x/n$.
